# What's the default print resolution for Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, printing, resolution, dpi

I'm trying to print a PDF from a Django template using headless chrome, I've designed the page for a 96DPI A4 resolution (794 x 1123), but It was too small on the printed PDF, so I've resized the page for a 150DPI resolution (1240 x 1754) but It was too big.

What's the default Google Chrome printing resolution? I don't want to keep trying different sizes on my template